# VSTS fails only when triggered by a commit

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

VSTS build definition is configured with 'continuous integration' enabled and when a commit is detected the build queued but it fails immediately, by immediately i really mean immediately, even before `Get sources` task. Also I don't get any log information from the detail page of the failed build, just a big white empty canvas, event with `system.debug` is set to `true`.

[image]

Furthermore I tried different branch settings in `Branch` property of `Get sources` task and `Branch filter` of the `CI` settings page, varying from 'develop', 'refs/heads/develop', '*', 'refs/heads/*' etc... and again no success

The agent running the build and the external git repository are behind a firewall (intranet). I assume the failure has somehow to do with that but have no idea how to work around it.

Has anybody experienced the same issues and has found a solution?

EDIT:

@jessehouwing pointed me to look into `_diag` and there I found this error message but still looking around to find information about the cause of this:

```
[2017-12-22 14:56:14Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Authentication failed with status code 401.
Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 14:56:13 GMT
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/0278d500-4cee-4ff3-ba11-a727fc9c10bb, Basic realm="https://tfsprodweu2.app.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
X-TFS-ProcessId: *************************************
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
ActivityId: *************************************
X-TFS-Session: *************************************
X-VSS-E2EID: *************************************
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-TFS-FedAuthRealm: https://tfsprodweu2.app.visualstudio.com/
X-TFS-FedAuthIssuer: https://ridercorp.visualstudio.com/
X-VSS-AuthorizationEndpoint: https://ridercorp.vssps.visualstudio.com/
X-VSS-ResourceTenant: *************************************
X-TFS-SoapException: %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3Csoap%3AEnvelope%20xmlns%3Asoap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F05%2Fsoap-envelope%22%3E%3Csoap%3ABody%3E%3Csoap%3AFault%3E%3Csoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3Esoap%3AReceiver%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3Csoap%3ASubcode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3EUnauthorizedRequestException%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ASubcode%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AReason%3E%3Csoap%3AText%20xml%3Alang%3D%22en%22%3ETF400813%3A%20Resource%20not%20available%20for%20anonymous%20access.%20Client%20authentication%20required.%3C%2Fsoap%3AText%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AReason%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AFault%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ABody%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AEnvelope%3E
X-TFS-ServiceError: TF400813%3A%20Resource%20not%20available%20for%20anonymous%20access.%20Client%20authentication%20required.
X-VSS-S2STargetService: 00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000/visualstudio.com
X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=ridercorp.visualstudio.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fridercorp.visualstudio.com%2F_apis%2Fdistributedtask%2Fpools%2F7%2Fmessages%3FsessionId%3D88f0cd4f-94e8-4b7b-a736-45663feb4c19%26lastMessageId%3D1606&redirect=1&context=eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiNDE3MWQ3YmEtYTc1ZS00YmYyLTlmYmEtZWU5MTA1N2E4YjQxIiwicXMiOnt9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90#ctx=eyJTaWduSW5Db29raWVEb21haW5zIjpbImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSIsImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSJdfQ2
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

EDIT jan/2/2018

in _admin/_AgentPool 's page, builds look happy (green), but with impossible build duration of 2 sec, but in build summary of the build definition it's actually red.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in the `_diag\agent_...utc.log` I found `Authentication failed with status code 401`, any idea why? manual trigger has no issues

Comment: That I do not, but now you have a more useful error message and an angle of investigation.

Comment: You could consider filing an issue in the Microsoft/vsts-agent repository on GitHub.

Comment: Sure, Thx for the help

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah  
Can you show the screen shot of the Agent Pools page (`https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool`, then slelect the agent which is used for the CI build)? And how did you config the agent, did you config the agent with proxy?

Comment: What's the result if you try it with a new build agent?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, my vsts agent is not configured using a proxy, Also I was experimenting with user login and `personal access token` for authentication but I not sure of which one I ended up using.

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah To narrow down the issue, can you remove the agent config and config with PAT again?

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah And please also make sure the PAT is not expired.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I just reconfigured the agent with a new PAT, but still same issue with repository ci, but this time I could not find any log error in the Agent_...utc.log file. on the other hand, scheduled build run just fine.

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah can you show a CI build summary page (similar as  https://imgur.com/a/6O829)? And what's the git repo do you build in VSTS, hosted in VSTS or github etc?

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah And does the PAT you used is Authorized with full scopes?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT yes, PAT is used with full scopes. CI Build Summary, does'nt show anything just like the first image shown in the Question section, still with missing option to download the logs (I guess because there isnt any). Before I could find an Auth error back in the Agent....utc.log but now, since reconfiguring the build agent, no errors are shown there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with VSTS that the error message will not display in some condition. We are investigating this issue. You can track the issue here: [CI trigger on Bonobo Git server](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/170706/ci-trigger-on-bonobo-git-server.html?childToView=172188#comment-172188).

The issue usually occurs when you use an external repository and VSTS cannot access to that repo successfully. According to the screenshot you provided, you are using "http" connection with Basic auth while VSTS requires "https" connection with Basic Auth. Get the build via the Rest API [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-build), you will see the detailed error message.

Comment: So I changed git repository to use https connection as suggested, my solution was to setup a reverse proxy instead of directly changing the bitbucket because I don't 'own' it, but that shouldn't matter. The git proxy is still inside the private network and is not accessible from the 'outside'. The error is now surprisingly that `The remote name could not be resolved` because I assume the repo is not accessed by a agent from the agents pool, right? if yes, then what do I have to do enable 'Repository CI' so that a build is triggered by a commit to my private git repository?

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah If your repository is located in a private network which cannot be accessed from internet by VSTS, you cannot enable the CI for it since VSTS need to keep querying your repo to check if there is new change committed by the polling time you set.